# How to put a transitioning underline under div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a container div get a blue underline when it is clicked.

I found a fiddle that I hoped would help me with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gvpr9w06/

Although I can not make it work, my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gzp97yjo/

My code:

Html:

```
<div class="AdministrationSettingsArea">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="linkContainer tablik">
            <div class="">Domains</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="linkContainer tablik">
            <div class="">Something new</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="linkContainer tablik">
            <div class="">Darkside</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.tablik {
display: inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.AdministrationSettingsArea a .linkContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width:33%;
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-align:left


}

.AdministrationSettingsArea a .linkContainer:hover{
    color:black;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
}

.tablik:after{
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.tablik.AdmClicked:after{
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
    $(".AdministrationSettingsArea a").on("click", function() {
        console.log($(this).find(".tablik"));
        if ($(this).find(".tablik").hasClass("AdmClicked")) return;

        $(this).parent().find(".tablik").removeClass("AdmClicked");
        $(this).find(".tablik").addClass("AdmClicked");
    })

})
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing from the original:

```
.tablik:after {
    content: '';
```

so the `:after` has no content, so is not displayed.

Comment: I won't even tell you the time i spent on this. Thank you, ill retire to a cave far, far away now...

Comment: Sometimes just needs a second set of eyes.